# Sync between devices - how to do that?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-phone, winjs

I'm making an Universal App for windows and windows phone 8.1. I have one variable (array) which stores some data. I'm looking for easy and fast way to sync this between multiply devices. What should I look for?

It can't be [roamingSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx), 255 characters is too little, my variable stores more.

Comment: From your own link: "The name of each setting can be 255 characters in length at most. Each setting can be up to 8K bytes in size and each composite setting can be up to 64K bytes in size. The sync engine may limit the total size of settings and files that can roam."

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation carefully. It says that the name for the setting - which means the identifier key you store the setting under - may not exceed 255 characters. There should be more than enough space in the roaming settings for you to store your array.

> The name of each setting can be 255 characters in length at most. Each setting can be up to 8K bytes in size and each composite setting can be up to 64K bytes in size. The sync engine may limit the total size of settings and files that can roam.